# Is this possible to fetch facebook friend's contacts number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am developing an application in iPhone and itegrate facebook and I successfully fetch all friends name and their ids so now my requirement is to fetch all friends contact number either phone number or personal phone number what ever they mentioned, so is this possible or facebook allow us to fetch contact unlike email address which I confirm that facebook not allowing us to fetch friends email. If facebook allow phone number then kindly let me know what permission key should I use?

**Edited**

```
ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook]; NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: FB_APP_ID, ACFacebookAppIdKey, @[ @"email", @"read_friendlists"], ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil]; [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:options completion: ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read Graph API documentation? What have you tried?

Comment: Simple answer - NO you can not :)

Comment: @ShahabQureshi Thanks, and others should learn this way to answer, instead suggesting non concern things.

Comment: @Josh That what you call 'non-concern' things are important too. You should try to understand this instead of getting angry.
That styling will help others understand your question in well manner.

Comment: I read docs but nothing got help, If I created thread over here then there is reason why I am asking and putting code also!

Comment: And, if you'd read the docs, you'd have acknoledged that it's not possible to get the phone numbers via the Graph API. But well... That's it from me.

Comment: I read docs but not in details that why I successfully able to get friends in first time try. And also stackoverflow basic motive is to get quick and helpfull answer, that why I come here to ask my query.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't make the user's phone numbers available via the Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/#fields), and **no, there's no workaround**.

Also, be aware that all `friends-*` permission will be rendered useless once Graph API v2.0 becomes mandatory on May 1st 2015.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: Bro I am using social framework as you can see that I am fetching facebook friend list.

Comment: "Bro", this is possible with Graph API v1.0, but not with v2.0. Read the docs! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids Quote: `In v2.0, the friends API endpoint returns the list of a person's friends who are also using your app. In v1.0, the response included all of a person's friends.`

Answer (score 0):

I found phone_number in their recent documentation, but Facebook has didn't mention it anywhere else.
Link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph

```
// Add the properties particular to the type restaurant.restaurant
restaurant[@"restaurant"] = @{@"category": @[@"Mexican"],
                     @"contact_info": @{@"street_address": @"123 Some st",
                                        @"locality": @"Menlo Park",
                                        @"region": @"CA",
                                        @"phone_number": @"555-555-555",
                                        @"website": @"http://www.example.com"}};
```